# How to add a B2B user in Azure Active Directory using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a requirement in which I need to add a B2B user in Azure Active Directory using Microsoft Graph.

Can any one help me out with any sample code or approach which can help me to meet this requirement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Invitation Manager API**. It's currently still in beta, but it allows you to manage and customize invitations sent out to B2B users in AAD.
For example, you can add an URL that the user is taken to once the invitation is accepted and add a custom message.

If you don't want to send the invitation email from Azure with the default layout, you can also choose to build and send your own email. The response of the invitation request contains the link the user must receive to accept the invitation. This give you a lot of control over the user experience.

[This page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/invitation_post) contains a description of the API and how to create requests.